# Using NodeHandle in callback

Tags: ros, c++, ros-melodic, nodehandle

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am making an initialization node for AHRS and I'm trying to get the initial bias of gyroscope by averaging the first 1000 readings that I get. I need to advertise the service only after I have received the correct amount of data points, but I can't figure out how to do this. In the version below, I tried making a global pointer to the node handle and while

```
        if(n.ok()){  
            ROS_INFO("NodeHandle working");
        }
```

runs properly and prints out "NodeHandle working", the service `ros::ServiceServer service = n.advertiseService("initialize_ahrs", initialization_handle);` is not being advertised. I have also tried using `boost::bind` as suggested in one of the answers to a similar [question](https://answers.ros.org/question/12970/how-to-use-nodehandle-in-callback/) but it didn't work either. I'm new to ROS and I don't know how else to get it working, could you, please, point out where am I getting it wrong?

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "ekf_imu_odom/initRequest.h"
#include "sensor_msgs/Imu.h"
#include "Eigen/Dense"
#include <geometry_msgs/Quaternion.h>
#include <tf/transform_datatypes.h>
#include "std_msgs/String.h"
#include <boost/bind.hpp>    

ros::Subscriber sub;
ros::NodeHandle * n_ptr;

int n_imu = 0;
int num_data = 1000;
double sum_accel [3] = {0};
double sum_gyro [3] = {0};

bool initialization_handle(ekf_imu_odom::initRequest::Request &req,ekf_imu_odom::initRequest::Response &res);

void imu_callback(const sensor_msgs::Imu::ConstPtr& data){
    ros::NodeHandle n = *n_ptr;
    // Getting data from the accelerometer
    double accel_data [3];
    accel_data[0] = data -> linear_acceleration.x;
    accel_data[1] = data -> linear_acceleration.y;
    accel_data[2] = data -> linear_acceleration.z;    

    // Getting data from the gyro
    double gyro_data [3];
    gyro_data[0] = data -> angular_velocity.x;
    gyro_data[1] = data -> angular_velocity.y;
    gyro_data[2] = data -> angular_velocity.z;

    // Making sure we get a 1000 points to get the avg
    if (n_imu < num_data){
        // Adding latest values to existing to the avg later on            
        sum_accel[0] -= accel_data[0];
        sum_accel[1] -= accel_data[1];
        sum_accel[2] -= accel_data[2];

        sum_gyro[0] += gyro_data[0];
        sum_gyro[1] += gyro_data[1];
        sum_gyro[2] += gyro_data[2];
    
        n_imu += 1;
    }
    else {    
        if(n.ok()){  
        ROS_INFO("NodeHandle working");
        }     
        ros::ServiceServer service = n.advertiseService("initialize_ahrs", initialization_handle);
        sub.shutdown();
    }   
}

bool initialization_handle(ekf_imu_odom::initRequest::Request &req,ekf_imu_odom::initRequest::Response &res){
    // Estimating gravity vector
    double g_v[3] = {0,0,0};
    g_v[0] = sum_accel[0] / num_data;
    g_v[1] = sum_accel[1] / num_data;
    g_v[2] = sum_accel[2] / num_data; 

    // Initial roll(phi), pitch(theta), yaw(psi)
    double phi = atan2(-g_v[1], -g_v[2]);
    double theta = atan2(g_v[0], sqrt(pow(g_v[1],2) + pow(g_v[2],2)));
    double psi = 0;

    // Creating quaternion from RPY to pass to ekf
    tf::Quaternion quat = tf::createQuaternionFromRPY(-phi,-theta, -psi);

    // Computing bias of the gyroscope
    double gyro_bias[3] = {0,0,0};

    res.gyro_bias[0] = sum_gyro[0] / num_data;
    res.gyro_bias[1] = sum_gyro[1] / num_data;
    res.gyro_bias[2] = sum_gyro[2] / num_data;

    // Converting from tf::Quaternion to geometry_msgs::Quaternion to pass as a msg
    quaternionTFToMsg(quat , res.init_orientation);

    ROS_INFO("sending back response: \n gyro_bias[1]: %f gyro_bias[2]: %f gyro_bias[3]: %f ", (double)res.gyro_bias[0], 
(double)res.gyro_bias[1], (double)res.gyro_bias[2]);
    ROS_INFO("quat x: %f y: %f z: %f w: %f ", (double)quat[0], (double)quat[1], (double)quat[2], (double)quat[3]);

    return true;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  // Initializing the node and creating the node handle
  ros::init(argc, argv, "ahrs_init_server");
  ros::NodeHandle n;
  n_ptr = &n;

  // Subscribing to get the data from accel and gyro
  sub = n.subscribe<sensor_msgs::Imu>("/imu/data", 1000, imu_callback);    
  ros::spin();      
  return 0;
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/357814/using-nodehandle-in-callback/) by [paradauz](https://answers.ros.org/users/56280/paradauz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2020-07-22

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [paradauz](https://answers.ros.org/users/56280/paradauz/) on 2020-07-23**:
Thank you, that worked.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2020-07-23**:
Awesome! Converted the comment to an answer so that this shows up as answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Fast glance: I think that the issue is that your `ros::ServiceServer service` goes out of scope as soon as the `imu_callback` exits and the service server is then destroyed. Note, there are likely better structures for this program, but I think if you declared `service` globally, and then defined it once you've received enough messages inside of the `imu_callback`, then I think this would work.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2020-07-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1